# Teradataml fastload error when using types dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to use Teradataml fastload module to upload a df into a table in teradata. Everything wotrks amazingly fine until the part that i want to optimize the actual table. If you do not assign any variable types to the columns they kind of tend to get assigned to bigger than necessary variable types. For exactly that raeson they do have the option to allow the use of a dictionary to assign desired columns to the correct variable types as seen per their documentation:

types:
Optional Argument.
Specifies the data types for requested columns to be saved in Vantage.
Types: Python dictionary ({column_name1: type_value1, ... column_nameN: type_valueN})
Default: None

```
        Note:
            1. This argument accepts a dictionary of columns names and their required 
            teradatasqlalchemy types as key-value pairs, allowing to specify a subset
            of the columns of a specific type.
               i)  When only a subset of all columns are provided, the column types
                   for the rest are assigned appropriately.
               ii) When types argument is not provided, the column types are assigned
                   as listed in the following table:
                   +---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
                   |     Pandas/Numpy Type     |        teradatasqlalchemy Type          |
                   +---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
                   | int32                     | INTEGER                                 |
                   +---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
                   | int64                     | BIGINT                                  |
                   +---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
                   | bool                      | BYTEINT                                 |
                   +---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
                   | float32/float64           | FLOAT                                   |
                   +---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
                   | datetime64/datetime64[ns] | TIMESTAMP                               |
                   +---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
                   | Any other data type       | VARCHAR(configure.default_varchar_size) |
                   +---------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
            2. This argument does not have any effect when the table specified using
               table_name and schema_name exists and if_exists = 'append'.
```

d) Save a Pandas DataFrame using types, appending to the table if it already exists
>>> fastload(df = pandas_df, table_name = 'my_table_3', schema_name = 'alice',
index = True, index_label = 'my_index_label',
primary_index = ['emp_id'], if_exists = 'append',
types = {'emp_name': VARCHAR, 'emp_sage':INTEGER,
'emp_id': BIGINT, 'marks': DECIMAL})

Everything sitting above is directly taken from the documentation.
When i do try to use the types argument this is the error i am getting:
fastload(test, 'fastloadtest','schemaname', types={'LATITUDE':VARCHAR})

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Miniconda\Miniconda3\envs\venv_indirect\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py in _init_items(self, *args)
110                 try:
--> 111                     spwd = item._set_parent_with_dispatch
112                 except AttributeError as err:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\teradataml\dataframe\fastload.py in fastload(df, table_name, schema_name, if_exists, index, index_label, primary_index, types, batch_size, save_errors)
307             _create_table_for_fastload(df=df, con=con, table_name=table_name, schema_name=schema_name,
--> 308                                        primary_index=primary_index, types=types, index=index, index_label=index_label)
309

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\teradataml\dataframe\fastload.py in _create_table_for_fastload(df, con, table_name, schema_name, primary_index, is_pti, primary_time_index_name, timecode_column, timezero_date, timebucket_duration, sequence_column, seq_max, columns_list, types, index, index_label)
653                                      schema_name=schema_name, set_table=False,
--> 654                                      types=types, index=index, index_label=index_label)
655     else:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\teradataml\dataframe\copy_to.py in _create_table_object(df, table_name, con, primary_index, temporary, schema_name, set_table, types, index, index_label)
1142                     for col_name, col_type in
-> 1143                     zip(col_names, col_types)),
1144                   teradatasql_post_create=pti,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\teradataml\dataframe\copy_to.py in (.0)
1141                   *(Column(col_name, col_type)
-> 1142                     for col_name, col_type in
1143                     zip(col_names, col_types)),

C:\Miniconda\Miniconda3\envs\venv_indirect\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py in **init**(self, *args, **kwargs)
1567                 )
-> 1568         self._init_items(*args)
1569

C:\Miniconda\Miniconda3\envs\venv_indirect\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py in _init_items(self, *args)
117                         ),
--> 118                         replace_context=err,
119                     )

C:\Miniconda\Miniconda3\envs\venv_indirect\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
181         try:
--> 182             raise exception
183         finally:

ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected, got 'varchar'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TeradataMlException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15556\2038172120.py in 
----> 1 fastload(test, 'fastloadtest','EBU_SANDBOX3', types={'LATITUDE':VARCHAR})

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\teradataml\dataframe\fastload.py in fastload(df, table_name, schema_name, if_exists, index, index_label, primary_index, types, batch_size, save_errors)
356     except Exception as err:
357         raise TeradataMlException(Messages.get_message(MessageCodes.FASTLOAD_FAILS),
--> 358                                   MessageCodes.FASTLOAD_FAILS) from err
359     return fl_dict
360

TeradataMlException: [Teradata]teradataml fastload() failed to load pandas dataframe to Teradata Vantage.

To me it just seems that it is expecting something else from the dictionary...just have no clue on what. Anybody that have a clue on this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry, just wanted to give as much detail as possible for the error. 
Mainly, the fastload method fails whenever i am using the types argument to assign variable types to specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i actually found the way to solve the issue.
You just need to import the variable types from teradatasqlalchemy.types and build the dictionary using those variable types. It will work as a charm afterwards